# Remove optional trailing slash before proxying

Tags: nginx, regex, proxypass

I would like to proxy some requests to another server, and to never send the trailing slash. I've come up with the following which is working, but is this really the best way? It feels a little bit like I'm taking the long way round, though maybe I've been staring at it for too long...

```
location ~ ^/proxy(?<proxy_to_path>.+[^/])/?$ {
    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:8080$proxy_to_path;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I do not like complex regular expressions in `location` directives, because `nginx` needs to test every URI requested. You can use an arguably simpler scheme by using one or more `rewrite...break` statements.

For example:

```
location ^~ /proxy/ {
    rewrite ^/proxy(.+?)/?$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

The `^~` modifier avoids any interference from any regular expression location blocks. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

The capture is non-greedy so that the optional trailing `/` will be removed.